# Problems adding chatvoice in html

Tags: html

I've been working on a website for about 5 months and i have been testing a lot of features like
posts, downvotes and upvotes, etc

One the features was chatvoice

The problem is that i haven't found any relevant information about making chatvoice a thing in an html website

Comment: What is the actual question? (It seems like you are looking for a general tutorial or a library that does it for you, both of which are off topic for this site)

Comment: I couldn't find any information about chatvoice and how to do it i just need a point of reference so i can code it, i can't code something i don't know how it works and by point of reference i mean a tutorial about how can i do it for myself not the entire code

Comment: The only thing called "chatvoice" I can find is a chatbot text-to-speech library. Is that what you are talking about? If not, what is "chatvoice"?

Comment: Well my definition of chatvoice is something similar to virtual assistants like alexa, you type a word and you get a voiceline

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe you asking how to convert speech to text (Speech recognition). You can use python Library for performing speech recognition, with support for several engines and APIs, online and offline.

Please find this [link](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) for installation.